# How to use Bootstrap components like Tooltip in custom Angular library

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap library components in custom Angular library like tooltip. I read the documentation of Bootstrap tooltip and it asks to make the following changes to your angular.json file

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/popper.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

But in Angular custom library, I can't add styles and scripts property to angular.json file. How do I apply the above changes in an Angular library?

Comment: Have you tried installing bootstrap with NPM/Yarn? If you do this correctly you shouldn't even need to use the angular.json file

Comment: I have installed bootstrap using npm install --save bootstrap and it installs "bootstrap": "^4.5.0" with my package.json. I want to specifically use tooltip component and for that the documentation says that I'll need popper.js, jquery and bootstrap. Can I provide you with more information to help solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know if bootstrap is already appearing in your Node_Modules? Do you need jquery, bootstrap, or popper for anything else in your app? If you don't, I would recommend using ng-bootstrap and can provide an answer accordingly. If you do, also let me know and I'll do what I can to help

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is appearing in my node-modules. And I don't need jquery, bootstrap, or popper for anything else in the app. I also tried installing ng-bootstrap but it doesn't work without bootstrap.min.css file. Could you provide me a solution with ng-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Since I only wanted to use the bootstrap styling, I could solve the above problem by installing @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap module using the following command

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Since ng-bootstrap depends on bootstrap, I installed bootstrap using the following command

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Imported the bootstrap.min.css file in my global style.scss file

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Used tooltip in my components by doing something like this

```
<fa-icon icon="database" data-toggle="tooltip" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="This is a tooltip text"></fa-icon>
```